# Subtracting lunch hours from a working hour time frame

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a form that would ask a user specifically the working hours of businesses 
below is what I'm using.

```
<tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="radio" name="mon" value="1"> Monday with No Lunch Break</td>
        <td colspan="4"><input type="radio" name="mon" value="2"> Monday with  Lunch Break</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Start time :AM<input type="time"  name="mon_strt_1" class="hour_field"></td>
        <td>End time :PM<input type="time" name="mon_end_1" class="hour_field"></td>
        <td>Start time :AM<input type="time"  name="mon_strt_2a" class="hour_field"></td>
        <td>End time :AM<input type="time" name="mon_end_2a" class="hour_field"></td>
        <td>Start time :PM<input type="time" name="mon_strt_2b" class="hour_field"></td>
        <td>End time :PM<input type="time"  name="mon_end_2b" class="hour_field"></td>
    </tr>
```

As you see I asked the user if on Monday the business would have a lunch break if so he would fill out the proper field and also clicking on the radio button. I would like to ask any help on how to make things easier for the user. That once he entered a time frame Like *8:00am to 6:00pm* then would enter the lunch break *12:00nn to 1:00pm* upon submission would return **WORKING HRS: 8:00am to 12:00nn , 2:00pm to 6:00pm**, Here's [a link](http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/) for a plugin that I used but i can't manage to use it in multiple forms. Note that i would also set the time from tuesday to friday. then sat to sun.

Comment: Time and attendance software generally includes the means to define "shift patterns", which is exactly what you are trying to provide.  Shift patterns are notoriously difficult to generalize. They consume more help desk effort at my company than any other single topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very simple. html and javascript:

```
<script>
function disablebreaks(disable){
    document.getElementsByName('break_strt')[0].disabled=disable;
    document.getElementsByName('break_end')[0].disabled=disable;
}
</script>
<form action="action.php" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="mon_break" value="false" onchange="disablebreaks(true)" />No break
<input type="radio" name="mon_break" value="true" onchange="disablebreaks(false)" />break
<input type="time" name="mon_strt" />
<input type="time" name="mon_end" />
<input type="time" name="break_strt" />
<input type="time" name="break_end" />
</form>
```

php in action.php:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['mon_break']?"working hrs: {$_POST['mon_strt']} to {$_POST['break_strt']}, {$_POST['break_end']} to {$_POST['mon_end']}":"working hrs: {$_POST['mon_strt']} to {$_POST['mon_end']}";
?>
```

This is untested, tell me if errors occur.

Comment: No Errors But. I think this is a good solution. Instead of subtracting. just display the break hrs instead. Wait error. JS wont work.

Comment: Fixed it. The getElementsByTagName returns an array, so I needed to add [0] at the end to refer to the first element with that name. Also, I forgot to put the onchange attribute on the second radio button.